# call internal view function in django

Tags: django, function, request

I want to call a function from another function in django. The function looks like this

```
def main_view(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
```

I dont want to have the url to main_view open so that user can access this url directly, instead they should face a login page(just a lot of checkboxes that the four right ones should be choosen) and after that submit, they should come to the template that the main_view function is rendering.

But, how do I actually call function internal that need a request GET input? 
Is there a way to do a GET request when calling the function?

//Mikael

Answer (score 1):

You can just pass the request from your other view into that one, like this:

```
def my_public_view(request):
    if user_passed_checkbox_test():
        return main_view(request)
```

Comment: It seems that since my login view, which I should access main_view from, have request POST, it seems that it sends a POST request to main_view. So in that case I need to change it from POST to GET.. if its possible.

Comment: Because your view isn't actually being wired up to a url - does it matter? Why do the request validation at all?

Comment: Because of this in the end av main_view,

return render_to_response('main_view.html',   {'wk':wk,},context_instance=RequestContext(request))

can I solve RequestContext(request)) without (request) ?

Comment: No - but you don't need your request to be a GET request to be able to pass it to RequestContext.